# Stylesheet changes and section alignment in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'm currently using `Berkeley` theme for my presentation using `LaTeX` beamer.
Question1:
I have multiple `sections` within the presentation but I do not want the `sections` to appear on the `title page`. I googled to see if can find something; no luck.

Question2:
How do I remove the list of authors from the pane in the left side?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\title[]{foo bar baz}
\author{foo\\ bar \\ baz}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{first}
first slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am using Texmaker on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use the `plain` option for the frame.
2. Use an empty optional argument for `\author`.

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
   \usepackage{color}
   \usepackage{textpos}
   \usepackage{framed}
   \usepackage{times}
   \usepackage{pgf}
   \usetheme{Berkeley}
   \usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
   \title[]{foo bar baz}
   \author[]{foo\\ bar \\ baz}
   \begin{document}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \begin{frame}[plain]
   \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \section{Introduction}
   \begin{frame}{first}
   first slide
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

The `plain` option will remove the sidebar and headline; if you want to keep those, and only remove the section information, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\title[]{foo bar baz}
\author[]{foo\\ bar \\ baz}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{first}
first slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. Just one last question that struck me now: Is it possible to explicitly remove a section for a particular frame?

Comment: @user2015933 just one section or all the sections?

Comment: So, essentially if you don't give the section name. the previous section name continuous, right?
I want one frame to have no section at-all.

Comment: @user2015933 then you can use the idea in the second example in my updated answer: `\begingroup\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}{}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}\endgroup`. (Notice the `\begingroup`, `\endgroup` that keep the change local).

Comment: Just an addition to your point:
if you want to remove subsections use:
`\setbeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}{}`
`\setbeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}{}`